# BIND 9: Testing the Reverse zone gives error, NS '' has no address records (A or AAAA)

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I am trying to create a ptr record. I read a tutorial on https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html and now I have spend almost the whole day to fix it but could not figure out what the problem is.

This is my Domain Zone File:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA server.info. emailid.gmail.com. (
                  2             ; Serial
             604800             ; Refresh
              86400             ; Retry
            2419200             ; Expire
             604800 )           ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  server.info.
@   IN  A   77.10.55.10
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
ns  IN  A   77.10.55.10
```

And here is my reverse DNS zone file:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA server.info. emailid.gmail.com. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  server.info.
10  IN  PTR server.info.
```

But when I check in terminal:

```
named-checkzone server.info /etc/bind/db.77
```

I get this error

```
zone server.info/IN: NS 'server.info' has no address records (A or AAAA)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Did you really _edit_ the local zone files? Those aren't meant to be altered at all.

Comment: yes I edit them. I just read the tutorial and edited the files. Did I made some mistake :(

Comment: The tutorial you linked to clearly stated to copy them and edit the copy. Time to put them back as they were.

Comment: Before making any changes I took a backup of all the files. I have all the files in original format. What should I do after putting all the files back.

Comment: The error message included in the question clearly specifies what it is that `named-checkzone` sees as a problem. It failed to resolve an address for the name `server.info` which your `NS` record refers to.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Tack för kommentaren. But Now I need to specify the result properly ?? Or What I have to do??

Comment: You'll want to have the `NS` records refer to names that have `A` and/or `AAAA` records.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Do I need to change the reverse DNS zone file and Give the IP here: "10  IN  PTR server.info." Instead of "server.info." Sorry for asking but its the first time I am working with this thing.

Comment: The value of the `PTR` is supposed to be the canonical name associated with the IP address that the owner name represents.

Answer (score 0):

prueba a la horade chequear
named-checkzone ip (ej: 77.168.192) /etc/bind/db.77
es el otro archivo.
en /etc/bind/named.conf.local hay dos archivos. recuerda, que para zona PTR es el segundo archivo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KON8u.png)